# Enviar array por ajax, y devolver otro array con los valores que coinciden

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas estoy obteniendo un array de un grupo de checkbox.

```
$(".add_adicionales").on('click', function() {
        //Cuando añadimos vaciamos la variable para que no se sobreescriban
        let serviciosAdd = [];
        //Obtenemos los checkbox seleccionados
        $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){
            serviciosAdd.push(this.value);
            console.log(serviciosAdd)
        });
        //Cambiamos la apariencia del desplegable y lo desactivamos
        $(".flecha_selector_adicional").removeClass("gira__flecha_adicional")
        $(".dropdown_adicionales").hide();
        mostrar_adicionales=true;

        let urlZonas = '/extraer-adicionales';
        
        $.ajax({
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
            type: "GET",
            url: urlZonas,
            data: {
                servicios: serviciosAdd
            },
            success: function (data){
                console.log(data);
            },
        });
    });
```

Este es el arreglo que obtengo en `serviciosAdd`

```
(2) ['1', '2']
    0: "1"
    1: "2"
    length: 2
    [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Lo mando por AJAX a mi controlador de Laravel.

```
public function extraerAdicionales(Request $request)
{
    $servicios = CasaElementosAdicionales::where('id', $request->servicios)->get();
    return with(['servicios' => $servicios]);
}
```

Pero cuando hago un `console.log(data);` solo recibo un elemento. He probado hacer un foreach también en el controlador pero sin éxito.

Comment: Recuerda que al final, lo que se transmite por `http` es texto. Por lo tanto, elige una forma de codificar tu Array al enviarlo para que del lado servidor puedas decodificarlo al objeto apropiado. Un formato común es JSON. Saludos

Comment: Hola @MauricioContreras estoy intentando así y tampoco, `return response()->json([` ..... No se si te refieres a eso?

Comment: Otra cosa que no comprendo es ¿Porqué envías datos en una solicitud GET? ¿Acaso no sería conveniente hacerlo en una solicitud tipo POST?

Comment: Tienes razón @MauricioContreras modificado a POST, pero sigo sin conseguir que me traiga el arreglo completo, siempre me trae el primero que elijo

Comment: El objeto que envías al servidor, escríbelo de la siguiente forma: `{'servicios[]' : serviciosAdd}`. Comenta el resultado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tras investigar encontre esto:

> El return implica una acción de cierre o terminación, por eso cuando
> itera el primer resultado el lenguaje interpreta que su función en el
> foreach termino
>
> si lo que deseas es imprimir los resultados puedes usar el metodo
> print() o guardar estos valores en un nuevo array con la función
> array_push()

Por eso hice lo siguiente, crear una variable y en cada iteración mandarlo a esa variable nueva, por último el return.

```
public function extraerAdicionales(Request $request)
{
    $serv = [];
    foreach($request->servicios as $key => $item){
        $servicios = CasaElementosAdicionales::where('id', $item)->get();  
        array_push($serv, $servicios);
    }
    return with(['servicios' => $serv]);
}
```